# Caesar Cipher java my way, doesnt work

Tags: java

I know there are bunch of topics about Caesar Cipher but I like to solve things my way. 
And as such it doesnt work ,but I think with some help I might get it to work my way.I am sure you all know that good feeling when you alone solve the problem.

So here is my idea.
To make array of chars that consist alphabet.
And String with message to code.
2 for loops. one outer to set char from message, 
and inner that scans thru alphabet array.
When letter from message meet char in array, it replaces him by 3rd (key of 3) char down in array.

Here is piece of code written by now:

```
    char[] alphabet = { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'o', 'p','r','s','t','u', 'v', 'z'};

    String message = " This is message for coding";

    message = message.toLowerCase();
    String codedMsg = ""; 


    for(int i = 0; i < message.length(); i++)
    {

        for(int j =0; j < alphabet.length; j++)
        {
            if(message.charAt(i) == alphabet[j])
            {
    codedMsg += alphabet[j +3 ];
```

It complies well, but I receive following error when run :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 23
        at sifra.main(sifra.java:19)
```

Comment: `alphabet[j + 3]` is not valid towards the end of iterations

Comment: Even if you fix this exception, the code still doesn't work correctly. String.replace will indiscriminately replace any occurrences of the characters, so you will potentially replace already replaced characters. E.g. "abcd" would become "gefg", not "defg".

Comment: I have solved it now, thx to Alfred Åkesson.
Just dont know should I place fixed program here or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're problem is that you have  `alphabet[j + 3]`. 
But because `j < alphabet.length`, so when `j =  alphabet.length - 2` say `alphabet[j + 3]` becomes `alphabet[alphabet.length + 1]` so you go outside the array.

To solve this you can use `alphabet[(j + 3)%alphabet.length]`.

**Now your code will run but not be correct.**

Because you always manipulate `message` it will be replaced many times in the inner loop.

```
for(int j =0; j < alphabet.length; j++)
        {
            if(message.charAt(i) == alphabet[j])
            {
                message = message.replace(message.charAt(i), alphabet[j + 3]); // THIS LINE IS THE PROBLEM
```

If we say that `message.charAt(i) = a` this will be true `if(message.charAt(i) == alphabet[j])` and all `a` in the sting will change to `d` so now `message.charAt(i) = d` and after 3 iteration of `for(int j =0; j < alphabet.length; j++)` the if statement will be true again and all `d` in the string will be replaced with `g` and so on. My solution to the problem is the following but there are probably many more:

```
     char[] alphabet = { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'o', 'p','r','s','t','u', 'v', 'z'};

        String message = " This is message for coding";

        message = message.toLowerCase();
        char[] messageArray = message.toCharArray();

        for(int i = 0; i < message.length(); i++)
        {
            for(int j =0; j < alphabet.length; j++)
            {
                if(message.charAt(i) == alphabet[j]){
                    messageArray[i] = alphabet[(j + 3)%alphabet.length];
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(String.copyValueOf(messageArray));
```

Comment: I want to make method to decode message, so I would need
alphabet[j-3]%alphabet.length, but it doesnt work.Shows index out of bounds again.Can you help me here.

Answer (score 2):

`alphabet[j + 3]` is going out of the size of the array `alphabet`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem, as mentioned in comments, is that `alphabet[j + 3]` goes out of bounds for `j` greater or equal to `alphabet.length - 3`. The solution I can suggest is changing `alphabet[j + 3]` to `alphabet[(j + 3) % alphabet.length]`, which will have a "cyclic" behaviour once the index goes out of bounds.

Comment: THx.Can you tell me why does it show index out of bounds when I write 
alphabet[j-3]% alphabet.length], when I try to decode message ?

Comment: @Sinology, It will happen for values of j less than 3, e.g. alphabet[2 - 3] % alphabet.length will give you -1

Comment: THx Egor, but doesnt %alphabet.length create cyclic behaviour in other direction too?I mean when it reaches 0index , it goes to the last index in array?

Comment: @Sinology, Definitely not, why should it? % is just the remainder operation, -1 % 25 won't give you 24, it will give you -1

Comment: So if I undestood correctly it cannot be done this way,since whenver I deduct smth from  alphabed(j), i will eventually receive negative index and out of bound ? Do you have any suggestion pehraps?

Answer (score 0):

as others have pointed out, your problem is that `alphabet[j+3]` will be out of bounds towards the end of the alphabet. Here's a fix that gets around that.

Replace this

```
message = message.replace(message.charAt(i), alphabet[j + 3]);
```

With this

```
if(j < alphabet.length - 3){
    message = message.replace(message.charAt(i), alphabet[j + 3]);
}else{
message = message.replace(message.charAt(i), alphabet[j + 3 - alphabet.length]);
}
```

This should loop the alphabet back to the beginning if it ends up near the end. For instance if the character `z` is input, it outputs `c`